# Is it possible to install SharePoint 2010 Server on the same Windows Server 2008 R2 machine with AD role installed?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I wonder if this could actually be done. I am in the process of creating a single VM for SharePoint 2010 development, with AD, all in a single box.

First, I configure AD first. Then, I install SharePoint 2010 server. Finally, I invoke SharePoint 2010 Configuration Wizard. However, on each try (I tried 4 times already, from scratch), it failed on Step 5, with error message like this: "failed to register SharePoint Services". FYI, I have no problem if I were installing and configuring SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2 machine without AD installed.

I wonder if this (SharePoint 2010 server and AD on a single VM) is ever possible. How to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try asking serverfault?

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, no, sorry. I wonder if anyone could help migrating this question to serverfault. TQ.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this is possible, and works quite well to have a self-contained VM that you can run without needing another lightweight W2K3 / W2K8 AD dedicated (or without external network connectivity).

Andreas Glaser has some nice information on how to do this kind of installation.
http://andreasglaser.net/post/2010/09/30/Install-SharePoint-e28093-Or-a-wrap-up-of-my-SharePoint-2010-installation-guide.aspx

You also have the Critical Path Training documentation, available for free (might require registration on their site : http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://www.criticalpathtraining.com/Members/ContinualLearning/Documents/CriticalPathTraining_SharePoint2010_VirtualMachineSetup_v1.6.pdf)

Hope it will help.

Comment: Many thanks to you. Before posting the question here, I already scanned Andreas Glaser post, and I am not sure if the AD configuration as per his tutorial meant for the same server or dedicated server. However, I will re-read his blog posts.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do this 
Install AD first

then go with the SharePoint installation

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, our SIT server enviroment is the same as your question, first you need install AD, and then sharepoint 2010, if you met SQL server error when installing central admin, then remember to install SQL server 2008 R2 version because i have met that before.